# A word or succinct descriptor for someone no longer found physically attractive

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or succinct descriptor for a person whose appearance has changed such that they are no longer found to be physically attractive by the speaker/writer.

The ideal answer should be gender-neutral (or readily gender-flexible) and avoid the implication that the essential "worth" of the person in question has somehow changed because the speaker/writer no longer finds them physically attractive. The purpose is simply to note the fact of the event, not make a value statement about it.

Comment: *no-longer found attractive* ***is*** pejorative.  They might be *weathered* or *aged* or *worn* but those qualities may well be endearing to loved ones or considered pejorative by the subject.

Comment: By non-pejorative, I meant that it should avoid the implication that the essential "worth" of the person in question has somehow changed because the speaker/writer no longer finds them physically attractive. Which is actually a better way of putting it - I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: *Past one's prime*: though that's pretty broad, not just about looks.

Comment: Whatever word you find, it will be pejorative, unless it is a hypocrisy. But in this case, you could say he/she still looks attractive as well.

Comment: _"Past one's prime"_ also suggests to me that the change in question is one that would be broadly recognized in the same way, which is not necessarily the case here.

Comment: @javaNoobs - I don't see why it should have to be pejorative - the idea is to simply note the change, not make a value statement about it.

Comment: Supposing that the speaker had once found person X physically attractive, you could say something like "X's once striking beauty/good looks had [or has or have] faded."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a gentle, and poetic way of saying a person is no longer the same fresh-looking attractive individual they once were. This does not necessarily entail that they are now physically unattractive, but it could be used that way.

[Bloom Of Youth](http://www.finedictionary.com/bloom%20of%20youth.html)

> 1. In the very bloom of youth, tall, slender, and handsome, he had a grace of manner not to be resisted.
> 2. But the Grant Girls had lost the Spring-time bloom of their youth.
> 3. In bloom of youth and beauty,
>      But yesterday she shone;
>      And her fond parents thought her
>      A mine of wealth unknown.

You could shift the onus onto sexual arousal and chemistry. The expression "to be turned on" is used in similar cases:

> - I'm not **turned on** by you
> - I used to be turned on by you

Alternatively, in plain simple words say the following with **used to be**

> - You used to be slimmer/prettier/more handsome/fitter. . .

Answer (score 0):

**She/he looks mature** is a hypocritical way to say the person does no look as young as before:

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mature)

> adjective, maturer, maturest.
>
> 1. complete in natural growth or development, as plant and animal forms: a mature rose bush.
>
> 2.ripe, as fruit, or fully aged, as cheese or wine.

Comment: This seems only relevant if the change in question is implicitly the result of aging?

Comment: Depends on the context. You can use both to say 'one has grown up', and 'one has grown old(er)'

Comment: @Jeff Yes, definitely this means only aging change. If someone has put on weight, this does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

How about "The bloom is off the rose" ?  or "Has aged gracefully"